# WordPress Two Level Filters on Getting Custom Taxonomy Terms

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy, terms, multi-taxonomy-query

I have a Custom Post Type Called `movie` and I have two taxonomies `genre` and `quality`  associated with that.
Now I need to get/filter all terms **IF**

```
genre = 'action'
AND
quality = 'HD'
```

Using this code I am able to get all terms which has genre term of action

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
                    'genre' => 'action',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    ) );
foreach ($terms as $term){
    echo $term->name;
}
```

but as I said I need to get all `action` terms which are also `HD`!
Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense querying with `get_terms` when:

```sql
genre = 'action'
AND
quality = 'HD'
```

**The reason is:** The only term that has taxonomy `genre` equals to `action`, is `action`. And the only term that has taxonomy `quality` equals to `HD`, is `HD`. If you constrain them with `AND`, then basically you have nothing. Since there's no term that satisfies both.

However, you can get `movie` custom posts that satisfies that criteria. Which means, you need movies with action genre and HD quality.

If that is the case, then you may use the `tax_query` argument in `WP_Query`:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'action',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'quality',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'HD',
        ),
    )
);
echo '<h1>Movies with action genre and HD quality:</h1>';
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo '<h2>Nothing is found</h2>';
}
```